# Is there a way to still use Checkgmail on ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: notification

[Checkgmail](http://checkgmail.sourceforge.net/) is still for me the best Gmail notifier. It allows to archive, delete, ... directly from the popup, it is small and don't use much brandwidth. I use it in my debian xfce desktop but I'm looking a way to use it also on ubuntu.

However, unity (since ubuntu 13.04) does not allow to display the checkgmail icon at the hot right corner of the screen.

I'm wondering if there are still checkgmail users in the ubuntu community and, if yes, how they use checkgmail with new versions if ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 is end of life >:D I assume we can 13.10?

Answer (score 0):

Try [gmail-indicator](https://github.com/bulletmark/gmail-indicator). The person who [made](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2158939&p=12714158#post12714158) this did this for 13.04+. From the read me:

> **INSTALLATION**
>
> Make sure IMAP access is enabled in the settings on your gmail
>   account. Then do:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install python-pip git gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1
> sudo pip install imapclient
> git clone http://github.com/bulletmark/gmail-indicator
> cd gmail-indicator
> make install  # Do this as your normal user, NOT as sudo/root.
> ```
>
> Edit your gmail username & password in ~/.gmail-indicator-rc. Also
>   change the command option there to something that works on your system
>   if you want an audible sound on new emails. Test that command manually
>   first. Disable, i.e. comment out, the command option if you don't want
>   new email sound. You can also use the folder command to check another
>   label/folder, e.g, [Gmail]/Important, rather than the default INBOX.
>
> IMPORTANT: Test the program. Check for reported errors, missing
>   packages, etc:
>
> ```
> ~/bin/gmail-indicator -di  # to test
> (<ctrl-c> to stop application)
> ```
>
> Search for, and then start, the gmail-indicator app in Ubuntu or GNOME
>   It will start automatically at log in and run in the background
>   checking for new mail. On Ubuntu, you can also start gmail-indicator
>   from the Ubuntu messaging menu.
>
> **REMOVAL**
>
> ```
> cd gmail-indicator  # Source dir, as above
> make uninstall      # Do this as your normal user, NOT as sudo/root.
> ```

Comment: I don't like writing my password in plain text. And there is no indicator applet...

Answer (score 0):

Checkgmail Ubuntu version has been no change in its code for a long time and now it is discontinued. That's why you can download [this version](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2677320/checkgmail) to replace it.
With this version of checkgmail you can change its colors by editing the script itself.

For a complete explanation, you can see at [Rcspam's Blog](http://rcspamsblogen.blogspot.fr/2014/09/i-checkgmail.html) where all is explain with details